# Sorting rectangular objects into a cupboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, input

So here we are packing objects and Both Length, Width and Height of object should be less than 50 for a good case and if any is more than 50 then the case is bad. I have written my program below but all cases are judged by the last case.

Sample input

2

20 20 20

1 2 51

Sample output

Case 1: good

Case 2: bad

```
T = int(input("Enter the number of test cases:\n"))
for i in range(1,T+1):
     print("Enter the values of the Length, Width, Height") 
     case = input()

#Length_1.
if case[1] == " ":
     L = int(case[0])
     #Width and heigth.
     if case[3] == " " and len(case) == 5:
          W = int(case[2])
          H = int(case[4])
     if case[4] == " " and len(case) == 6: 
          W = int(case[2:4])
          H = int(case[5])
     if case[3] == " " and len(case) == 6:
          W = int(case[2])
          H = int(case[4:6])
     if case[4] == " " and len(case) == 7:
          W = int(case[2:4])
          H = int(case[5:7])
         
#Length_2.
if case[2] == " ":
     L = int(case[0:2])
     #Width and height.
     if case[4] == " " and len(case) == 6:
          W = int(case[3])
          H = int(case[5])
     if case[5] == " " and len(case) == 7:
          W = int(case[3:5])
          H = int(case[6])
     if case[4] == " " and len(case) == 7:
          W = int(case[3])
          H = int(case[5:7])
     if case[5] == " " and len(case) == 8:
          W = int(case[3:5])
          H = int(case[6:8])

for i in range(1,T+1):
     if L > 50 or W > 50 or H > 50:
          print("Case ", i,":"," bad", sep='')
     else:
          print("Case ", i,":"," good", sep='')
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  From your examples, both cases seem to provide correct answer unless this is the expected results and you are getting something different?  If that is the situation, please clarify.

Comment: those are the expected results but as for my program if the last case is bad then all will be written bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is that all cases are judged by the properties of the last case (though, as has been noted, it is not clear what this means for the results of your code as given), then it could be because when `case` is assigned in:

```
T = int(input("Enter the number of test cases:\n"))
for i in range(1,T+1):
    print("Enter the values of the Length, Width, Height") 
    case = input()
```

it is assigned anew during each iteration. Consequently, the previous input gets lost.

---

Edit:
The following code solves your problem by turning `cases` into a list:

```
T = int(input("Enter the number of test cases:\n"))
cases = []
for i in range(1,T+1):
    print("Enter the values of the Length, Width, Height")
    dimensions = input()
    c = dimensions.split(" ")
    cases.append(c)
 
for j, case in enumerate(cases):
    if int(case[0]) > 50 or int(case[1]) > 50 or int(case[2]) > 50:
        print("Case ", j,":"," bad", sep='')
    else:
        print("Case ", j,":"," good", sep='')
```

In this suggestion, the user input is automatically split into the different values using `split()` instead of manually doing it via `if` statements as it has been the case in your original post (this snippet assumes that the input provides values separated by a single space).

Comment: how do i judge the cases now because they are now lists

Comment: To access the values stored in the case lists, use square brackets with the index of the respective entry.

Comment: Sorry but im really lost, check my program before making an array

Comment: If you want to access the entry of a specific case and then check its value provided by the user (what you currently do in the `if` statements), you will now, for example, have to refer to `case[i][1]` instead of `case[1]`, with `i` being the index of the case you want to access from the case-list.

Comment: I have added a code snippet to my post, which solves your problem. Let me know if you have any questions.